# Invalid use of qualified-name with Qt on Linux

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt project that builds just fine under Windows 7 or 10. When I try to build it on Centos 7 using Qt 5.9.1, I get "Invalid use of qualified-name" errors when I try to take the address of a static class member. For example:

myClass.h

```
class myClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  . . .
  static QMutex  mtxLock;
  static QHash<QString, QString> hshMap;
};
```

myClass.cpp

```
QMutex myClass::mtxLock;
QHash<QString, QString> myClass::hshMap {{"key", "value"}};

void myClass::myFunction()
{
  QMutexLocker(&myClass::mtxLock);       // Invalid use of qualified-name
  if ( myClass::hshMap.contains("key") ) // No error
  {
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A variable name for the locker is missing  -  `QMutexLocker lock(&myClass::mtxLock);`

Comment: It's interesting that it is an error: `Class(argument);` simply means that you're constructing an instance of `Class`, then immediately destructing it. Such code should compile but of course won't do what you wish it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable name for the locker is missing. For the compiler it looks `QMutexLocker &myClass::mtxLock;` - like a local variable with qualified name.

You could fix it like this:

```
const QMutexLocker lock(&myClass::mtxLock);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/np3TFf)</kbd> (gcc 4.8 because it's the CentOS 7 default compiler).

This is actually under "Bug #6" on the [Curiously Recurring C++ Bugs at Facebook](https://youtu.be/3MB2iiCkGxg).

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. And I can't believe the Windows compiler did not pick it up.

Comment: I still find this error in my code :) together with some missing `throw`s.